# Reading Data Files

Tags: java

I am writing a program in my AP java class and I am very confused. The program is supposed to read a data file using another program called EasyReader. The program consists of an Object class that finds the largest number, medium number, and smallest number. The Test class is supposed to read the data file (numbers.bat) that gives a set of numbers and the program is supposed to print the largest, medium, and smallest  of all lines of the data file. However, it is reading only one line of the data file (the middle one) instead of all three. It is displaying

`Largest = 7.3 Medium = 5 Smallest = 3.2`

Please help. Thank you!

Here is the Object class:

```
public class Numbers 
{

    double small;
    double medium;
    double large;

    public Numbers(double A, double B, double C)
    {

      if(A>=B && A>=C)
      {
        large = A;


        if(B>=C && B<=A)
        {
          medium = B;

          small = C;
        }
        else
        {
          medium = C;
          small = B;
        }

      } 
      else if(B>=A && B>=C)
      {
          large = B;


            if(A>=C && A<=B)
            {
              medium = A;

              small = C;
            }
            else
            {
              medium = C;
              small = A;
            }


      } 

      else 
      {
          large = C;


            if(A>=B && A<=C)
            {
              medium = A;

              small = B;
            }
            else
            {
              medium = B;
              small = A;
            }

      }

    }



        public double large()
        {
            return large;

        }
        public double medium()
        {
            return medium;

        }
        public double small()
        {
            return small;

        }
    }
```

Here is the Test class:

```
public class NumbersTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        EasyReader file = new EasyReader("numbers.dat");
        double value1 = file.readDouble();
        double value2 = file.readDouble();
        double value3 = file.readDouble();


        value1 = file.readDouble();
        value2 = file.readDouble();
        value3 = file.readDouble();




         Numbers nums = new Numbers(value1, value2, value3);

         System.out.println("Largest = " + nums.large()  + " Medium = " + nums.medium() + " Smallest = " + nums.small());
    }


}
```

And last the data file (numbers.bat)

```
4 9 2.5
3.2 5 7.3
12 8.2 9.1
```

The output right now:

```
Largest = 7.3 Medium = 5.0 Smallest = 3.2
```

The expected output:

```
Largest = 12.0 Medium = 7.3 Smallest = 2.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers constructor only does anything if your value1 (A) is larger or equal to the other two. If it isn't it will leave small,medium and large at 0.

Edit: Expanding the answer here as it looks cleaner.
So in your number constructor

```
public Numbers(double A, double B, double C)
{



            if(A>=B && A>=C)
            {
                large = A;


            if(B>=C && B<=A)
            {
                medium = B;

                small = C;
            }
            else
            {
                medium = C;
                small = B;
            }

        }

    }
```

You only have one main if statement checking if A is the largest, and the rest are nested into it. You would also need an if statement for if B or C are the largest.

```
public Numbers(double A, double B, double C)
{

  if(A>=B && A>=C)
  {
    large = A;


    if(B>=C && B<=A)
    {
      medium = B;

      small = C;
    }
    else
    {
      medium = C;
      small = B;
    }

  } else if if(B>=A && B>=C)
  {
    //B is the largest, add code to determine medium and small as you did before
  } else {
    //C is the largest, add code to determine medium and small as you did before
  }

}
```

Comment: value1 is the value read from the datafile. Isn't it supposed to be determined as large, medium, or small when the program prints?

Comment: Thank you! You did help me with my logic, however, now that its working it is reading only one line of the data file (the middle one) instead of all three. It is displaying Largest = 7.3 Medium = 5 Smallest = 3.2. Do you know how I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: That is because every time you call file.readDouble(); you read the next double value in your file. You are currently calling it 6 times and only making use of number 4 to 6, which is the second row in your file. To get all doubles in a file you would need to call it until you reach the end of the file. Either by hardcoding it to do it 9 times for your example or putting it in a loop. You would then also need to update your Numbers class with something like an add numbers function that checks if the new numbers  are the largest medium or smallest